# Set href visible using Php in Drupal 7 if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 local website and I have a popup when you enter the website.
In this popup, I want to show a button leading to an article, if the user is logged in, or else two buttons leading to the login page and the register page.
The popup is an html file.
I tried with javascript(hiding the buttons and make them visible when the html file loads) but I can't find how to check if the user is logged in.
Is there a way to achieve that using only php, and how can I do that?I am a new developer and I don't know php well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(user_is_logged_in()) {
  echo '<a href="some link">Private</a>';
} else {
  // show two buttons
}

?>
```

Have a look at the api [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7)

Comment: and how can I put it into the html file?also, is there a way to make the buttons(a hrefs) visible?